# ListView is Null

Tags: java, android, listview, bluetooth

My co-captain is annoying and broke my scouting app when he tried to add in Bluetooth.

Whenever I run this, I get an `error that listview is null`. The `listview` pops up a dialog and lists the discover-able devices that it can connect to. I have tried changing the id per instructions on another post and made sure there were discover-able devices available before running but nothing has worked. Please help! This is my

**auto.java:**

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            switch (state) {
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: STATE OFF");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING OFF");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE ON");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING ON");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};

private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)) {
            int mode = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            switch (mode) {
                //Device is in Discoverable Mode
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Enabled.");
                    break;
                //Device not in discoverable mode
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Able to receive connections.");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Not able to receive connections.");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connecting....");
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connected.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Broadcast Receiver that detects bond state changes (Pairing status changes)
 */


  private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ACTION FOUND.");

            if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mBTDevices.add(device);
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getName() + ": " + device.getAddress());
                mDeviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(context, R.layout.device_adapter_view, mBTDevices);



                 if(lvNewDevices == null)
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " its null you fool and kaitlyn is the best", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 }
                 else{
                     lvNewDevices.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);
                 }
            }
        }
    };
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver4 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)) {

                BluetoothDevice mDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                //3 cases:
                //case1: bonded already
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BND_BONDED.");
                    mBTDevice = mDevice;
                }
                //case2: creating a bone
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDING.");
                }
                //case3: breaking a bond
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_NONE.");
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: called.");
        super.onDestroy();

        /*unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1);
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2);
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3);
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver4);
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button next  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.auto);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });
        Button btnONOFF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnONOFF);
        btnEnableDisable_Discoverable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDiscoverable_on_off);

        mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();

        //  btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        // etSend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver4, filter);
        connectbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connctbtn);
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

       lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(Auto.this);

        autoGearVal = (EditText) ((findViewById(R.id.autoGears)));
        autoBallVal = (EditText) ((findViewById(R.id.autoBalls)));
        match = (EditText) ((findViewById(R.id.matches)));
        teamVal = (EditText) ((findViewById(R.id.team)));


        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        saveVal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        btnStartConnection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartConnection);

        File dir = new File(path);
        dir.mkdirs();

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        connectbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final ConnectDialog connectDialog = new ConnectDialog();
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog,null);
                connectDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Connect Dialog");
            }
        });


        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Gear_Location, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                sideValue = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        lvNewDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNewDevices);
    }


    public void send(String etSend) {
        byte[] bytes = etSend.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
        mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);
    }


    public void enableBT(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: enabling/disabling bluetooth.");
        enableDisableBT();
    }

    public void startConnection(View view) {
        startBTConnection(mBTDevice, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
    }

    public void startBTConnection(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "startBTConnection:Initializing RFCOM Bluetooth Connection.");
        mBluetoothConnection.startClient(device, uuid);
    }

    public void enableDisableBT() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: Does not have BT capabilities.");
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: enabling BT.");
            Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBTIntent);

            IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
        }
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: disabling BT.");
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

            IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
        }

    }

    public void btnEnableDisable_Discoverable(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "btnEnableDisable_Discoverable: Making device discoverable for 300 seconds.");

        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2, intentFilter);

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void btnDiscover(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Looking for unpaired devices.");

        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Canceling discovery.");

            //check BT permissions in manifest
            checkBTPermissions();

            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {

            //check BT permissions in manifest
            checkBTPermissions();

            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
        }
    }


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        //first cancel discovery because its very memory intensive.
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on a device.");
        String deviceName = mBTDevices.get(i).getName();
        String deviceAddress = mBTDevices.get(i).getAddress();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceName = " + deviceName);
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceAddress = " + deviceAddress);

        //create the bond.
        //NOTE: Requires API 17+? I think this is JellyBean
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to pair with " + deviceName);
            mBTDevices.get(i).createBond();
            mBTDevice = mBTDevices.get(i);
            mBluetoothConnection = new BluetoothConnectionService((Auto.this));
        }
    }
```

**XML file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvNewDevices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnStartConnection"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />

        "more nonsense about buttons"


</RelativeLayout>
```

**error:**

```
12-17 21:40:00.405 13246-13246/com.example.owen.scoutingapp2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.owen.scoutingapp2, PID: 13246
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND flg=0x10 bqHint=4 (has extras) } in com.example.owen.scoutingapp2.Auto$3@8132b08
                                                                               at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1003)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.owen.scoutingapp2.Auto$3.onReceive(Auto.java:151)
                                                                               at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:993)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**auto.java.151:**

```
lvNewDevices.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);
```

Comment: Can you please post your logcat, and point in which line of your posted code, the error occurs?

Comment: Just added the logcat and line where the error happens

Comment: move this line of code `lvNewDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNewDevices);` above `lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(Auto.this);` and try. You are calling `onClickListener()` on the view which is not initialized.

Comment: To understand better your flow. Is auto.java activity in its onResume() state waiting for an intent intercept by the broadcastreceiver? It seems to me that mBroadcastReceiver3 receive the intent BEFORE auto.java set its layout and/or before lvNewDevices is being initialized

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found it. In this line you are trying to set the OnItemClickListener. But the ListView is not initialised yet:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver4, filter);
    connectbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connctbtn);
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(Auto.this);

    autoGearVal = (EditText) ((findViewById(R.id.autoGears)));
    autoBallVal = (EditText) ((findViewById(R.id.autoBalls)));
```

You need to set the field 'lvNewDevices' before you do

```
lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(Auto.this);
```

so move this line

```
lvNewDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNewDevices);
```

over this

```
 lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(Auto.this);
```

and try again.

Jojii